# Rails 3.2 XML rendering using an xml builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

What used to work with Rails 3.1.0 was:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
...
    def myAction
      ...
      data = render_to_string( :template => "reports/report.xml.builder", :layout => false)
      ...
    end
end
```

With Rails 3.2 I am getting a deprecation warning. How do I render an arbitrary xml builder view with Rails 3.2?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
render(:template => "reports/report.xml.builder", :layout => false)
```

Rails 3.2 wants

```
render(:template => “reports/report”, :formats => [:xml], :handlers => :builder, :layout => false)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I've `'_test.xm.builder'` partail so I have to use render_to_string it work like this

```
render_to_string(partial: "/assignments/test", :formats => [:xml], :locals=> {:abc=>'xyz'})
```

this will cure :)